# python getattr multiple levels with values being passed as well

Tags: python

so I've been reading up on getattr, and was wondering what the equivalent of

```
example = val1.val2.val3(item)
```

would be. 
So I get that you have to use nested getattr to implement multiple levels attributes

```
example = getattr(getattr(val1, "val2"), "val3")
```

but how do I represent the object being passed in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
val3 = getattr(getattr(val1, "val2"), "val3")
example = val3(item)

# Or simply:
example = getattr(getattr(val1, "val2"), "val3")(item)
```

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use a neat function from the standard library [operator.attrgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter). Here a little example on how to use it.

```
from operator import attrgetter

from collections import namedtuple

# Define some objects
Foo = namedtuple('Foo', 'attr')
Bar = namedtuple('Bar', 'subattr1')

instance = Foo(attr=Bar('this_is_my_value'))

retriever = attrgetter('attr.subattr1')
result = retriever(instance)
print(result)
```

This executed will give you

```
this_is_my_value
```

Comment: attrgetter() is great indeed. Any one knows a good way for settings multi lever attributes? So: `l1.l2.l3.l4.l5 = 1`, but then of course programmatically.

Comment: I had a look at the standard library and didn't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be worked out with safe eval. If the nested attributes are available, this will work.

```
fn_pointer = eval("val1.val2.val3", {}, {"val1": val1})
fn_pointer(item)
```